# How to install Snow Leopard from XP on MacBook?

Tags: snow-leopard, windows

The only OS installed on my MacBook is a XP pack 3.

I would like to install Snow Leopard on XP but when I boot from CD , It does not work I have a "panic kernel error"

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to make a bootable usb disk.

Transmacfor for Windows (2-week trial) can format USB drives for mac and restore .dmg files to USB drives.

http://www.asy.com/scrtm.htm

Download Transmac and install in Windows
In the right-side panel of Transmac, right click on your USB Drive >> Format Disk >> Format with Disk Image
Point to your .dmg file and click Open.

your USB Drive has to be at least 8GB.

Comment: but I have Snow leopard on CD ?